# How do I go through random item from DropDownList with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

I want to automatic go through random items from the DropDownList1.
It's working, but it's going by the order first to last, and I want to go through items randomly.

```
/* function to automatic select DropDownList1 items */
function selectFromDropdown(selector, text) {
  $(selector).find('option').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == text) {
      $(selector).val($(this).val());
      return false;
    }
  })
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  let numberOfTimes = 0;
  const time = 1000 //3s
  let values = [];
  $('#DropDownList1').find('option').each(function() {
    values.push($(this).text())
  });
  console.log(values);
  const interval = setInterval(function() {
      selectFromDropdown('#DropDownList1', values[numberOfTimes])
      if (numberOfTimes == values.length - 1) {
        clearInterval(interval);
      } else {
        numberOfTimes = numberOfTimes + 1;
      }
    },
    time);
});
```

Here the snnipet: https://jsfiddle.net/lucasangelo_/17Lgr0kc/6/

Comment: do you need a list of values from the select or the option text?

Comment: I want to go through the dropDownList values ​​automatically and postback each on.

Comment: Note that your first function could simply be `$(selector).find(`option[text="${text}"]`).prop('selected', true)`, if the `select` does not have the `multiple` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is:

```
  /* function to automatic select DropDownList1 items */
    function selectFromDropdown(selector, text) {
      $(selector).find('option').each(function() {
        if ($(this).text() == text) {
          $(selector).val($(this).val());
          return false;
        }
      })
    }

    function getRandomNumber(min, max) {
      return (Math.random() * (max - min) + min).toFixed(0);
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
      let numeroDeVezes = 0;
      const tempoEntreCadaChamada = 1000 //3s
      let valores = [];
      $('#DropDownList1').find('option').each(function() {
        valores.push($(this).text())
      });
      console.log(valores);

      const interval = setInterval(function() {
          const randomNumber = getRandomNumber(0, valores.length - 1);
          const randomItem = valores[randomNumber];
          //console.log(randomItem);
          selectFromDropdown('#DropDownList1', randomItem),
            console.log(`${numeroDeVezes} - Chamou do PostBack para ${randomItem}`);
          //__doPostBack('LButton3', 'OnClick');
          if (numeroDeVezes == valores.length - 1) {
            console.log("Percorreu todos, mata o setInterval");
            clearInterval(interval);
          } else {
            numeroDeVezes = numeroDeVezes + 1;
          }
        },
        tempoEntreCadaChamada);
    });
```

Thank you boys!

Comment: Code answer made by @MathiasFalci
Thank you bro ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get random values from a `select`, then you can use the next function:

```
function getRandomValuesFromSelect(selector, numberOfItemsWanted)
{
    var valuesSelected = [];
    var childrenSelect = document.getElementById(selector).children;

    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfItemsWanted; i++) {
        var randomValue =  Math.floor(Math.random() * childrenSelect.length);
        var randomOption = childrenSelect[randomValue];

        if (valuesSelected.indexOf(randomOption.value) < 0) {
            valuesSelected.push(randomOption.value);
        } else {
            i--;
        }
    }

    return valuesSelected;
}
```

Then you could call it like so:

```
getRandomValuesFromSelect("DropDownList1", 3);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answer FF-.
But I don't think this one could help me, I've tried but doesn't work.
Now I brougth my code, check it out: https://jsfiddle.net/lucasangelo_/1qo2mhg5/26/

Comment: I wanna automatic go through every item (in order or randomly) from select (DropDownList) and post back each one, setting time out to 3 seconds each one.
Thank you guys!

Comment: why do you wanna go through that trouble, if you can just select your `DropDownList1` from code behind?

Comment: Hi my friend, thanks for answer buddy. 
Well, because I'm beginner and I thougth it could be done by JavaScript easily. I'm learning FF- Thank you again for answer me. God bless you.

Comment: when you say code behide do you mean using C#?
It ins't good to use JS instead?

Comment: Yeah, I meant on C#. You could do a foreach going through every item on your DropDownList, but take note that what you are asking now is not what you asked on your original question.

Comment: I already fixed the post, thank you Dev. Now it's better to understand.